# Отметить цветом определённые данные из колонки БД MySql с помощью PHP

Tags: php, html

Вот такая задача: нужно сделать проверку страховки авто. Проверка заключается в следующем: пользователь вводит данные в таблицу, таблица отправляет всё в базу (в том числе и введённую дату), а проверочный скрипт запускается кроном и проверяет совпадает ли дата в базе с текущей. 
Если совпадает хоть одна, то отправляет письмо, и если зайти на страницу с таблицей, то хотелось бы пометить красным цветом просроченные строки, а остальные зелёным.

Не ругайте за страшный код, только курсы закончил.

```
<table>
   <caption><strong>Страховка автомобилей</strong></caption>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ФИО</th>
                <th>Марка</th>
                <th>Фирма</th>
                <th>Номер</th>
                <th>Дата окончания</th>
                <th>Удалить</th>
                <th>Обновить</th>

            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php
            foreach($list as $item)
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $item['fio'] .  "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $item['model'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $item['firm'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $item['number'] . "</td>";

                echo "<td>" . $item['date'] . "</td>";
                ///////////МОИ ПОПЫТКИ///////////////
                $date1 =  date('Y.m.d');
                $result = $pdo->query('select count(*) from test')->fetchColumn();
                $count = "SELECT COUNT(date) FROM test";//$date2 =  Date('01.m.Y');
                $cmd2 = $pdo->prepare($count);
                $cmd2->execute();
                $result = $cmd2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);//кол-во строк
                echo $result;
                for ($i = 1; $i < $result; $i++) 
                  {
                    $sql = "SELECT id = '$i' FROM test WHERE date <= '$date1'";
                    $cmd = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                    $cmd->execute();

                    $l_records = $cmd->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    if ($l_records) {
                        $color = "<td style='background-color: red;'>";
                        $color2 = "</td>";
                        echo "<td style='background-color: red;'>" . $item['date'] . "</td>";
                    } 
                     else 
                       {
                        echo "<td style='background-color: greenyellow;'>" . $item['date'] . "</td>";
                        $color = "<td style='background-color: greenyellow;'>";
                        $color2 = "</td>";
                       }
                    echo $color . $item['date'] . $color2;
                }
                ////////////МОИ ПОПЫТКИ//////////////

                ?>
```

Что выходит:

1. Весь столбец с датой стал красным вне зависимости от данных
2. Зелёный так и не появился
3. Там, где я пытался считать кол-во строк ($result). Я внёс 3 строки а в переменной получилось вместо 3 строк, число 333 (откуда?).

Нужно ещё отлавливать проверку **за месяц** до истечения введённой даты (про это вообще молчу).

Письмо отправлю сам, но отправка сойдёт для случая даже если хотя бы одно значение даты удовлетворяет просроченному (желательно за месяц до установленной даты). Сейчас, при совпадении даты - письмо отправляется.

Comment: попробуйте сначала выбрать и подготовить в удобном виде все данные, а потом уже написать их вывод в хтмл.  При этом, задайтесь вопросом, как максимально получиь нужные данные средствами СУБД, а не обработкой в пхп.

Comment: А разве $l_records не получает отфильтрованные данные? В моем случае вся база всегда отображается таблицей. Может возможно поискать в ней? Или все это плохая затея? Данных всего будет штук 20.

Comment: хз я не читал. мне достаточно увидеть выполнение запросов в цикле вперемешку с выводом td-шек, чтобы понять что так не надо писать код. Разделяйте логику и представление, это залог чистоты и понятности кода.

Comment: и раскраску в css-классы вынесите. по их названиям хоть понятно будет, почему таблица раскрашене так как раскрашена, и легко поменять цвет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно всё получилось решить. Вот такой запрос отправляю в БД:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, fio, model, firm, number, date, CASE
WHEN date <= CURDATE() THEN -1
WHEN date > CURDATE() AND date < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) THEN 0
ELSE 1
END as status
FROM test";
$cmd = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$cmd->execute();
```

Соответственно тут -1 это либо текущая дата либо просроченная
0 это дата за месяц до истечения (относительно ткущей даты)
1 значит всё в порядке
Всё это записываю в status.

Цвета я выставляю таким образом:

```
<table>
                <caption><strong>Страховка автомобилей</strong></caption>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ФИО</th>
                <th>Марка</th>
                <th>Фирма</th>
                <th>Номер</th>
                <th>Дата окончания</th>
                <th>Удалить</th>
                <th>Обновить</th>

            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php
            foreach($list as $item)
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $item['fio'] .  "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $item['model'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $item['firm'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $item['number'] . "</td>";
                switch ($item['status'])
                {
                    case -1: echo "<td style='background-color: red;'>" . $item['date'] . "</td>"; break;
                case 0: echo "<td style='background-color: yellow;'>" . $item['date'] . "</td>"; break;
                case 1: echo "<td style='background-color: green;'>" . $item['date'] . "</td>"; break;
                }
```

Перебираю всё в цикле относительно status и "кейсами" говорю какой цвет для какой ячейки назначить. Ячейки у меня с датами. Поэтому просроченные будут красными, за месяц до выхода срока, но не равные текущей дате и не меньше неё, ячейки будут жёлтые, а все остальные будут зелёными.

А вот файл, который будет запускаться по крону раз в день ежедневно и в случае если приближается срок и срок истёк и срок равен текущей дате - будет отправлять письмо менеджеру с текстом о том, что нужно обновить дату страховки:

```
require_once 'db_connect.php';
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);


$date1 = new DateTime(time());
$date1->modify('+1 month');

$date1 = $date1->format('Y-m-d');

$sql = "SELECT id, fio FROM test WHERE date <= '$date1' AND date > CURDATE()";
$cmd = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$cmd->execute();

$l_records = $cmd->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($l_records) {
echo '<span style="color: red">'.'Нужно продление страховки'.'</span>';
//echo "Нужно продление страховки";
$str = ""; 
   // var_dump($l_records);
    foreach ($l_records as $item)
            {
       // var_dump($item);            
        $str .= $item['id']. ", ";
            }
            $mail="alexeyalexeev95@outlook.com"; // ваша почта
            $subject ="Проверка страховки" ; // тема письма
            $text= "Обнаружена страховка с истёкшим сроком годности!!! $str"; // текст письма
            if( mail($mail, $subject, $text) )
            { echo 'Успешно отправлено!'; }
            else{ echo 'Отправка не удалась!'; }
}
    else {
    //echo "Страховка актуальна";
    echo '<span style="color: greenyellow">'.'Страховка актуальна'.'</span>';
}
```

str будет содержать информацию о тех полях, которые нужно обновить.
Зайдя на основную страничку, менеджер увидит всё в цвете.